# Follow a GameObject and change camera view at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I am working on a 3D side scroller game in which my camera is following my character using `Vector3.lerp`.

Currently my camera is looking at the player from a side but at certain points I want the camera to transition to TopView (look at the character from the top) while also keeping a certain height from the character.

I have done this by creating camera settings naming SideView and TopView. Now the problem is that the camera does transitions from SideView to TopView but during transition the camera shakes when it is at the end of the `lerp` (when the camera is almost at the target position).

**How to make this smooth (stop camera shake)?**

Note: both camera and character are moving.

Here the source code of my camera follow:

```
void LateUpdate () 
{
    if(currentCameraSettings != null && target.transform != null)
    {
        targetPos = SetCameraTargetPos(target.transform);

        if(duration != 0)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,targetPos,(Time.time - startTime ) / duration );
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = targetPos;
        }

        SetCameraRotation();
    }
}
```

`SetCameraTargetPos` returns the target position after adding height and z-axis distance from the target character.

Comment: I can try to provide an image illustrating the camera movement. an pin point the place where the camera starts to shake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have the wrong situation for a `Lerp`. I think what you want to use here is `MoveTowards`.

```
float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
```

if its still "jaggedy" for you, try using `Time.smoothDeltaTime`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bad english.

If you want prevent to camera shaking your use rigidbody properties.
Freeze x,y,z.

or

Create empty object inside the your object with all the same control settings and followed the empty space not the your object.

Comment: I am using character controller not RigidBody. and yes the camera is not directly following my character but another empty GameObject that follows my character only along x-axis.

Comment: character controller already have a rigidbody component.
did you try freeze y and z axis?

Comment: Well actually I am trying to transition my camera, my Character is only moving along x-axis. And it is the Camera that shakes not the Character. Also I don't see any freeze y and z axis option on `CharacterController`